# Docker: how to install RCurl to Docker container?

Tags: r, docker, installation, rcurl

I am trying to install a RCurl to Docker container, remix of [this](https://github.com/glamp/r-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) Dockerfile, but failure. So

**How can I install RCurl to Docker container?**

> **Dockerfile**
>
> ```
> $ cat Dockerfile 
> FROM r-base 
> RUN apt-get -y install r-base
> RUN pip install rpy2
> RUN apt-get -y install libcurl4-openssl-dev
> #setup R configs
> RUN echo "r <- getOption('repos'); r['CRAN'] <- 'http://cran.us.r-project.org'; options(repos = r);" > ~/.Rprofile
> RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('yhatr')"
> RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('ggplot2')"
> RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('plyr')"
> RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('reshape2')"
> RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('forecast')"
> RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('stringr')"
> RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('lubridate')"
> RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('randomForest')"
> RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('rpart')"
> RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('e1071')"
> RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('kknn')"
> RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('RCurl')"
> RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('rjson')"
> ```
>
> **Docker instalaltion failure**
>
> ```
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RCurl_1.95-4.8.tar.gz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 916934 bytes (895 KB)
> ==================================================
> downloaded 895 KB
>
> * installing *source* package ‘bitops’ ...
> ** package ‘bitops’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** libs
> gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-3.3.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c bit-ops.c -o bit-ops.o
> gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-3.3.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c cksum.c -o cksum.o
> gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-z,relro -o bitops.so bit-ops.o cksum.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
> installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/bitops/libs
> ** R
> ** preparing package for lazy loading
> ** help
> *** installing help indices
> ** building package indices
> ** testing if installed package can be loaded
> * DONE (bitops)
> * installing *source* package ‘RCurl’ ...
> ** package ‘RCurl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> checking for curl-config... no
> Cannot find curl-config
> ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’
> * removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RCurl’
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>   ‘/tmp/RtmpJrfUvL/downloaded_packages’
> Warning message:
> In install.packages("RCurl") :
>   installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
>  ---> b8de6bc67379
> Removing intermediate container e8c17d0306ef
> ```

Comment: You are doing it wrong. _Install binary packages_.  See what our Rocker project does.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel so by rocker manual, I need to build a container with this Dockerfile [here](https://github.com/rocker-org/hadleyverse/blob/master/Dockerfile) under hadleyverse that was referred from `Installing binaries` [here](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/wiki)? Unfortunately, the hadleyverse wiki is empty

Comment: SO, the (numerous !!) Dockerfiles of the 'Rocker' project which create eg the r-base container you start from. _See what we do_ to make your life easier.

Comment: you should read https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/ as having numerous RUN is looking for trouble

Answer (score 0):

Dirk suggested to install from binaries which referred to hadleyverse build in rocker [here](https://github.com/rocker-org/hadleyverse):

> Docker image providing RStudio + rmarkdown/pandoc/latex + R package ecosystem from Hadley Wickham

so we are getting a lot of extras besides the basic `RCurl`.

Below you build the container from the docker image and then start it with a directory from your host, leaving you in interactive shell, bash. There you can open the `R` session with `$ R` on the command line where the command `install.packages('RCurl')` works.

```
$ docker build -t 20170127_r .

$ docker run -v ~/Desktop/20161213_project/:/project -it 20170127_r bash`
```

**Dockerfile**

```
 #R with RCurl 
 #https://github.com/rocker-org/hadleyverse/blob/master/Dockerfile
 #
 FROM rocker/verse
 MAINTAINER "Carl Boettiger and Dirk Eddelbuettel" rocker-maintainers@eddelbuettel.com

 ## Install some external dependencies. 
 RUN apt-get update \
   && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends  \
     default-jdk \
     default-jre \
     icedtea-netx \
     libbz2-dev \
     libcairo2-dev \
     libgdal-dev \
     libicu-dev \
     liblzma-dev \
     libproj-dev \
     libgeos-dev \
     libgsl0-dev \
     librdf0-dev \
     librsvg2-dev \
     libv8-dev \
     libxcb1-dev \
     libxdmcp-dev \
     libxslt1-dev \
     libxt-dev \
     mdbtools \
     netcdf-bin \
   && . /etc/environment \
   && install2.r -e -r $MRAN rJava \
   && R CMD javareconf \
   && apt-get clean \
   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/ \
   && rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages/ /tmp/*.rds
 ## tidyverse, devtools and related R packages already inherited from rocker/verse

 ## httr authentication uses this port
 EXPOSE 1410
 ENV HTTR_LOCALHOST 0.0.0.0
```

where it is not clear which packages are sufficient for the `RCurl` installation.